# How do I write handles from a MATLAB GUI into a .m file?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am trying to create a GUI for a script that receives paths and matrix names from the user (via uigetdir and uigetfile functions as well as edit text fields), and finally upon pushing the "Run" button writes these handles into a .m file and runs another script.
Essentially, in the end it should create a file called 'RunName'.m that looks something like:

> base_path = get(handles.BasePathEdit,'String')
>
> file_name = get(handles.FileNameEdit,'String')
>
> main             % runs the main script with the preceding variables defined as they were

and run it.

I'm guessing the script would run successfully if I just write it like that under the 'Run' push-button function, but I would still like for it to create a .m file as described.

Thank you very much for you help,
All the best.

Comment: To run successfully, your `RunName.m` would need to have the variable `handles` in scope (which won't happen the way you wrote it). This seems a very convoluted way to run scripts ... what exactly is the final intent of having this file generated ?

Comment: The simplest thing would appear to be to write a function, rather than a script, and pass the variables in that way.

Comment: Hoki, you're right. I didn't realize that. Sorry, this is practically my first week to programming anything, I'm still trying to get the hang of it.
@nkjt, that's what I'm doing for the moment. I guess what I'm trying to do is basically create a run file with all the variables particular to that run, that will be saved in the working folder for future reference. A kind of executable log file of sort.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of accomplishing this is to write a function that executes upon the pressing of the 'run' button that reads the values from the GUI and the proceeds with the main script. In guide, this is simple - right-click on the 'run' button, and under 'View Callbacks', select 'Callback'. Then you can use the usual syntax `get(handles.RELEVANT_TEXT_BOX,'string')` etc to read the resr of the data in. You can then pass this to your main function, or you could then just copy and pase your script straight into the callback.

Comment: Thank you, @srthompers, but in fact that is what I am doing now. What I am missing is a convenient way to write this data into a separate file. What I want is a log file that is fixed in a certain template, and is executable\loadable by the GUI. 
What do you thing about just using 'save' and creating a .mat file with all of the workspace? Perhaps I can load it later to the GUI and then just run it that way...